# How to do this Delphi procedure in BCB XE

Tags: delphi, c++builder

I need to use IncMonth procedure directly from SysUtils header but I don't know how to use `SysUtils.IncMonth()` in C++ Builder XE.

Anyone can help me how to do that in C++ Builder XE?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: This question is quite vague. How to use it ? E.g. like `TDateTime MonthLater = IncMonth(Now(), 1);` ? Take a look at [`this site`](http://www.functionx.com/cppbuilder/topics/datetime.htm), maybe you'll find your answer there.

Comment: @TLama I need to use IncMonth procedure **DIRECTLY** from SysUtils header.. It will clash if I don't use it **DIRECTLY** from SysUtils header because I have another Utils header which have same IncMonth() procedure..

Comment: I see. So then you have to specify that namespace in your call. Like this `SysUtils::IncMonth()`.

Comment: You're welcome! I've made an answer for this question, but you should consider to delete [`this one`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15607243/960757) as it seems to be a possible duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you encounter ambiguity between two functions, you'll need to specify namespace of the function you want to call to let the compiler know which one you're calling. In your case it will be:

```
SysUtils::IncMonth()
```

In a code it might look like this:

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    TDateTime TwoMonthsLater = SysUtils::IncMonth(Now(), 2);
    ShowMessage(DateToStr(TwoMonthsLater));
}
```

Whenever you get a compiler error or warning, you may take a look at [`the reference`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Compiler_Errors_And_Warnings_%28C++%29_Index), which almost always contains also an example how to resolve a certain error or warning.